# How do you disable mlinks-mode in emacs nxhtml mode

Tags: emacs, nxhtml

I am using emacs with nxhtml mode.  I find mlinks-mode to be a pain because I use PHP constants for my paths which trips up mlinks-mode - so when I inadvertently click on a link, I get a debug stack trace.

Whenever I enter into an HTML block, the mlinks-mode gets enabled.  I have tried setting my init file or mlinks-mode options to disable it, but it seems to be getting loaded dynamically regardless of these settings.  Is there a way to prevent nxhtml from loading this mode unless I want it to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `M-x customize-variable RET mlinks-mode-functions RET` and remove the `nxhtml-mode` entry.

Comment: That worked!  Only hiccup was that after entering M-x customize, I had to navigate through the customization interface to find the settings for mlinks-mode which was under the Hypermedia/Mlinks category.  I'm sure there was a command-line way of doing it, but I don't know it.  Thank you.

Comment: Ah yes, it was intended to be `customize-variable`.